# Valid authentication methods for WebDav (that work with windows)

Tags: c#, authentication, basic-authentication, webdav

I am writing a webdav-server. While the authentication method "Negotiate" works, I need custom credentials of the user (email/password). So the users windows-credentials do not really help. 
So I tried basic authentication instead, but windows (7 and above) does not allow that authentication method for webdav. 
(I know this can be changed using regedit)

Is there any authentication method available that fits my needs?

- can be used with webdav
- can be used for custom credentials
- works on windows (without registry-change)
- works on other platforms

Answer (score 2):

Without much experience in WebDAV authentication I suggest you take a look at Basic auth over SSL, which should work in Windows 7+.